# How to get the list of all posts I've upvoted via the API?

Tags: support, up-votes, api

I'm looking for a way to get the list of all my upvotes on Stack Overflow, however after looking through the [API list](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), seems there is no way to achieve that.

And I know I can view my upvotes in votes tab, however I'm looking for an official API to query the list.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. Particularly not for other users. Voting is private here.

Comment: @Catija, then what about users/me? I merely want to retrieve all my own upvotes

Comment: The same trick as in the linked (duplicate or not) question works; just replace `/users/{ids}/posts` with `/posts`.

Comment: @Glorfindel: On the one hand, yes; on the other hand, it should be self-evident that querying literally every post on an SE site, 100 at a time, and checking to see if each is upvoted is not really performant and will run out your API quota right quick. So, since a useful answer to the other question is *not* at all useful in this case, they are not really dupes.

Comment: @NathanTuggy hmmm, that makes sense. Makes me wonder why you can't *filter* on the fields in the *filter*.

Comment: Related question on Stack Apps: [List of Votes by Authenticated users](https://stackapps.com/q/4725/34061)